# How to concatenate two column values inside List?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to concatenate two column values inside a list and respectively select all columns but all I can achieve is get a concatenated column inside list with no other existing columns data .As I loose other columns data inside list because I'm using `select` to concatenate .

**Linq Query:**

```
 data = data.Select(m => m.Name = m.Id + m.Place).ToList(); // m=>m kindoff with concatenation
```

I need data to be modified like column name `Name` will hold `Id+Place` and I get all columns data intact (`Place`,`Address`,etc) can be many more  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update specific fields you could use the foreach clause. This will update the values in place without needing to call ToList as well.

```
data.ForEach(m => m.Name = m.Id + m.Place);
```

Comment: cool that's the hack i'm so dumb not even gave a shot at foreach . cheers

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this...

```
data = data.Select(m => new
{
    Name = $"{m.Id} {m.Place}", // Edit to add string interpolation
    Place = m.Place,
    Address = m.Address,
    etc = m.etc
});
```

While you don't "need" to include a name for m.Place, m.Address, etc. (Visual Studio will name them appropriately based off the of the property name), I find that it's easier to read if you keep the syntax consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select new`:

```
var data2 = from c in data
            select new
            {
                Name = c.Id + " " + c.Place,
                Place = c.Place,
                Address = c.Address
            };
```

Or:

```
var data3 = data.Select(c => new { c.Address, Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.Id, c.Place)});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already two answers which should work for you. But they give you a list of anonymous objects.

The below will give a list of your custom class(*instead of anonymous object*) with the desired result.

```
var result = data.Select(m => new Category 
                                { Name = m.Name = m.Id + m.Place,
                                  Place = m.Place} ).ToList();
```

Update `Category` with your class name (*the same class which data is a collection of* or a different DTO/View model with those property names).

Comment: nice one but this will `(new)`erase the existing data i'm afraid .